# Записать в бд код любого языка

Tags: php

Пытаюсь записать в бд поля с формы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
После отправки обращаемся в `php`, где происходит добавление в бд:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['name'] ) && isset( $_POST['task'] ) ) {
    $name = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['name']));
    $task = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['task']));
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `{$db_table}` (`name`, `content`) VALUES ('{$name}', '{$task}');";
    mysqli_query( $link, $sql );
    header("Location: /");
    exit;
}
```

Запись происходит удачно даже если добавляю теги или `php` скрипт (`<?php echo "test!"; ?>`), а вот когда добавляю код скрипта `<script>alert('ая-яй!')</script>`, то ничего не происходит. Помогите разобраться, почему не могу скрипт записать в бд?

Comment: Вы забыли экранирование спецсимволов sql, и у вас дыра в безопасности под названием sql-инъекция. Из-за неё же и не работает.

Comment: @andreymal спасибо за наводку) Могли бы подсказать какие функции нужно применить?

Comment: Вместо mysqli - pdo с плейсхолдерами.